# Confusion about using module.function() to create an object

Tags: python, class, object

When I build an array object (e.g `nd`) by using a function in the `numpy` module, I wondered why the object could use the array attribute, such as `shape`, without a class to instantiate it.

```
import numpy as np
nd = np.random.randn(3,5)

nd.shape  #（3，5）
print(type(nd)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

As far as I know, `randn` is a function in module, `nd` belongs to the class `numpy.ndarray`. So, without using `nd = np.ndarray()`, but when using `module.function()`, how can an array object be created? I am confused about this.

Comment: You've called the function and its return value is a numpy array...

Comment: If you did `type(np.random.randn)` - that'd be different...